# Why wont this text display after checking the box? I am using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am practicing JQuery and cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Can anyone take a look? When the box is checked the div should unhide.

https://jsfiddle.net/pnewelljr/wfdsu40n/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#isAgeSelected').click(function () {
        $("#txtAge").attr("style", "display:block");
    });
});

<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>
```

Comment: It does work. But your jsFiddle does not have Jquery selected?

Answer (score 0):

I got your code to work by changing it to the following:

```
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function () {
    $("#txtAge").toggle();
});
```

Further details on toggle() can be found at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Also, your jsfiddle seems to be missing the jQuery framework load.

Comment: `toggle()` will work but it requires correct initial state of a checkbox and `#txtAge` visibility. Otherwise it will show info when checkbox is not checked. In my answer `#txtAge` visibility is based on checkbox state.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to include jQuery in fiddle (using menu on the left). Then, when you have jQuery available, you can use it (see your browser's console output, there are errors like "*$ is not defined*").

Then you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#isAgeSelected').click(function () {
        $("#txtAge")[$(this).is(':checked') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
});
```

It will hide/show `#txtAge` depending on checkbox' state.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I could think of:

```
$(function(){
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
var checked = $(this);
if (checked.is(':checked')) {        
  $("#txtAge").show();
  } else {
  $("#txtAge").hide();
  }
})
});
```